# Create index vector efficiently in matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, vectorization

Given three positive integers x,y, and z, such that x>y. What is the most efficient way to create the following vector:

```
1,2,3,..,x-y,x+1,x+2,x+3,..,2x-y,2x+1,2x+2,2x+3,..,3x-y,3x+1,...,..,zx+1,zx+2,zx+3,..,zx-y
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [vectorize selection of ranges on a 1D vector in Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15100751/vectorize-selection-of-ranges-on-a-1d-vector-in-matlab)

Comment: @natan The answers to each question may be relevant for the other, but it is quite a different question. Hence I would recommend to leave this question open.

Comment: let's agree to disagree...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem can be seen as a matrix, in which you add `(1:x-y)` to the various rows, and `(0:z)*x)` to the various columns. This can be done efficiently using [bsxfun](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html). To obtain the final result, you have to flatten the matrix to a column vector with `(:)` and transpose it to get the desired row vector:

```
>> x = 10; y = 7; z = 3;
>> vector = bsxfun(@plus, (1:(x-y)).', (0:z)*x);
>> vector = vector(:).'
vector =
     1     2     3    11    12    13    21    22    23    31    32    33
```

Comment: you beat me by a min. ditto ans. +1

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly.. Only change `(0:z)` to `(0:(z-1))` I think?

Comment: I assumed the last bit of your example was `zx+1,zx+2,zx+3,..,zx + x-y`, note the extra `x`. As you wrote it, the last value `zx-y` is smaller than `zx + 1`, was that what you wanted?

Comment: @BasSwinckels +1 but `'` includes a conjugate (my usual quibble). For future reference, I suggest to replace it by `.'`, so that the code works for complex numbers too

Comment: @LuisMendo I know, I know, I am always lazy with that. But the problem stated positive integers ...

Answer (score -1):

Using matrix multiplication (column vector x row vector), an alternative solution is:

```
x = 10; y = 7; z = 3;

a = (1:x-y).'*ones(1,x-y) + ones(x-y,1)*(0:x:x*(z-1)); 

a = a(:).';
```

Comment: Fails for: `x=12;y=4;z=5`